# Odoo - PosBox Less Printer Disconnect

Tags: raspberry-pi, odoo

I have installed to develop the Odoo Point of Sale. I have in the same raspberry the Odoo Point Of Sale and the Posbox Less(to manage printer).

At moment the Odoo Point Of Sale is running fine and the Posbox Less too. I can see in http://IP:8069/hw_proxy/status the printer

The problem is to print tickerts from Odoo Point Of Sale. It's display an icon to LAN disconnect and the printer isn't print.

In the official documentation doesn't talk about any configuration file or whatever:

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/point_of_sale/overview/setup.html#id2

I am a bit confused and I would appreciate help with this topic.

Thanks!